# How to change the default web page in Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux-mint, web, defaults

I am using Linux Mint 12. I am trying to change the default web page, so that people using guest-session will open a specific web page instead of Linux Mint's corny default site.

Also, please note that when I installed Chromium, the Linux Mint default page comes up there too. There must be a global variable somewhere. It would likely be in the same place that Ubuntu keeps the same variable. Does anyone know where this variable is?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: The browser that is installed by default. Firefox. Version 8.0, Also Chromium 15.0.874.106

Answer (score 1):

Go to Firefox settings. Go to the section on the home page. Change Firefox Home to Custom URLs. The default Firefox homepage found on other distros is about:newtab. Not sure if this will apply to other users, but it should help on your user.
-Posted from Linux Mint 19
[image]